# How number of particles in a photon gas is not conserved?

Tags: statistical-mechanics, thermal-radiation, bosons

How can I understand that " In photon gas, particle number is not conserved"

Answer (score 0):

The walls making a boundary of your system can absorb and emit photons.

This not only means that particle number is not conserved but also that the chemical potential $\mu$ vanishes.